# BASH automatically adding quotes to string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a simple bash script that executes a command with one string variable.  Upon execution bash adds single quotes to the string variable making the command useless.  How do I execute the command without the quotes from the bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash
key=$(echo $1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch \<\<\<$key
```

the output I get is

```
~/scripts$ bash -x nvidia on
++ echo on
++ tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
+ key=ON
+ sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch '<<<ON'
```

the two commands I want to run without the quotes are either

```
sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<ON
```

or

```
sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF
```

Comment: Escaping and single quotes are equivalent.

Comment: If you are using `bash` 4 or later, `key=${1^^}` eliminates the need for `tr` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the quotes, it's that `sudo` doesn't execute the command via the shell. So metacharacters like `<<<` don't have any special meaning when they're given as `sudo` arguments. You need to invoke the shell explicitly:

```
sudo bash -c "tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<$key"
```

But there doesn't really seem to be a need to use a here-string for this. Just use:

```
echo "$key" | sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to quote the `<<<` operator. `sudo` doesn't read from its standard input by default; it passes it through to the command it runs.

```
sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<< $key
```