# BASH is automatically adding single quotes to string variables

Tags: arrays, regex, linux, string, bash

[This problem is almost similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150672/bash-automatically-adding-quotes-to-strin)

I am trying to write a script that executes a custom command on a CSV string variable. The problem is when I define the string variable from another variable(from an array in this case), the bash function is enclosing the elements in single quotes and the command(anothermycommand) is breaking. And if manually define the string variable with a value, it is not enclosing the variable and the custom command(anothermycommand) is working fine when passed to the command.

```
function myfunction {
    declare  -a ARR=($(mycommand $2 | grep "Server:" | awk '{print $2}')) #variable assignment
    echo ${ARR[@]}
    declare -a ARR=('SERVER-123' 'SERVER-432') #static assignment - Values are same to above varibale assignment
    echo ${ARR[@]}
    declare CSV=$(echo ${ARR[@]}| tr ' ' ',')
    anothermycommand  -t ${CSV}
```

If I use variable assignment (line2) for ${ARR[@]} values, the command is breaking because ${CSV} is enclosed in single quotes. And if I use direct assignment(line4), the command is working fine. I think it is related to array assignments, from line2 the elements are enclosed in single quotes.

For line 3 and 7 bash -x debug

```
+ echo 'SERVER-123' 'SERVER-432'
+ anothermycommand  -t 'SERVER-123,SERVER-432'
```

For line 5 and 7 bash -x debug

```
+ echo SERVER-123 SERVER-432
+ anothermycommand  -t SERVER-123,SERVER-432
```

Output of `mycommand $2 | grep "Server:" | awk '{print $2}'`

```
SERVER-123
SERVER-432
```

Bash info

```
 $ echo $BASH_VERSION $BASHOPTS
 4.3.48(1)-release checkwinsize:cmdhist:complete_fullquote:expand_aliases:extglob:extquote:force_fignore:interactive_comments:login_shell:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
```

How to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried checking your code with https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck tool? It will analyse your code and give you some recommendations. Related to your issue, it points to this one for example: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2207

Comment: If you put `mycommand $2 | grep "Server:" | awk '{print $2}'` at the beginning of `myfunction`, what will it print ?

Comment: I tried with `mapfile -t array < <(mycommand $2 | grep "Server:" | awk '{print $2}')` following https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2207, but no change.

Comment: Please add output of `mycommand $2 | grep "Server:" | awk '{print $2}'` to your question.

Comment: @Philippe It prints line1:`SERVER-123`line2:`SERVER-432` (line separated) without any single quotes.

Comment: added command output

Comment: Can you add output of  `echo $BASH_VERSION $BASHOPTS`

Comment: Thansk @Philippe, added bash info.

Comment: I didn't get what you experienced, even with bash 4.3. Maybe you can paste a complete reproduceable code.

Comment: The output you are seeing is just how `-x` works; the single quotes are not part *of* the value, just part of the *displayed* command line.

Comment: That said, you should be quoting your parameter expansions. See http://shellcheck.net.